# How to let user erase previous input and output in C++?

Tags: c++, switch-statement, calculator, erase

I'm in my first weeks of learning programming and I now have a assignment to build a "well functioning" calculator. It has to be able to:
-Add
-Subtract
-Multiply
-Divide
-Reset
-Be able to erase/go back

I think I've figured out the first 5 things but I'm stuck at "Be able to erase". How do I make it so when I've written 5+5, I can erase that and write 5-5?

I've posted my code below and as always, please tell me if I made any typos or should build my code in a diffrent way. :)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    while (true)
    {
        char val;                                                          
        float num1, num2;                                                   
   
        cin >> num1;                                                        
        cin >> val;                                                         
        cin >> num2;                                                        

        switch (val) {                                                      

        case '+':                                                           
            cout << num1 << val << num2 << " = " << num1 + num2 << endl;    
            break;                                                          
        case '-':                                                           
            cout << num1 << val << num2 << " = " << num1 - num2 << endl;    
            break;                                                          
        case '*':                                                           
            cout << num1 << val << num2 << " = " << num1 * num2 << endl;    
            break;                                                          
        case '/':                                                           
            cout << num1 << val << num2 << " = " << num1 / num2 << endl;    
            break;                                                          
        default:                                                           
            cout << "Not valid operator";

        }

    }

 
}
```

Comment: not sure if I understand what you want to do. YOu need not write any code for a user typing `5+5` (no enter) then press the backspace key twice, then `-` and `5` to have `5-5`, its your terminal that does that

Comment: can you include example input and expected output?

Comment: The cin is storing multiple vars, not_a_number. It's not a giant string.

Comment: "The cin is storing multiple vars, not_a_number. It's not a giant string" and? `cin >> num1;` blocks and waits until the user entered a whole line, only then this and the following lines can read from the stream

Comment: anyhow, its not clear what you want to do. Please add example input and expected output

Comment: Sorry, my english is a bit rusty I'll try to explain.

Comment: When the user writes 5+5 it will output "5+5=10" and then restart the loop. What I'm wondering is if its possible to let the user erase the "5+5=100" output and write in something else. So if the user does multiple calculations they dont get stacked in a list. 

I hope I made my problem a bit more clear.

Comment: you can include example user input and the output that your code should procude in the quesiton. You can still [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74654004/edit) the question

Comment: There is no standard or platform-independent way of erasing the terminal output.

Comment: @beeboo That's not possible in standard C++. There do exist third party libraries that can do that, but they are platform specific. It also seems like too advanced of a task for a beginner. Probably you should ask whoever set the task for more detail on what they meant.

Comment: @beeboo Nice code BTW, better than the newbie code we typically see.

Comment: @john: I agree, it's more C++ish. I wonder why students get these calculator tasks. IMHO, calculators are one of the most difficult things to build. Students IMHO should have knowledge of lexing, parsing, building an AST and some graph theory. Do the professors know how difficult it is?

Comment: @beeboo: in which semester of your studies did you get this task? Did you have lessons on lexing, parsing, building compilers, graph theory?

Comment: Imaging a user on a physical teletype. Ink is put onto paper, and there is no way of removing it.

Comment: @john Sorry for my superlate answer, but thanks! The deadline is today so I will just turn it in as it is now and hopefully get some feedback. :) Thanks again for all the help!

Comment: @ThomasWeller I got this task after 4 weeks, and to answer your question, no. Either we havent got to that part or its in the course.

Answer (score 0):

You can use function `system(char *command)`.

Cleaning the terminal in Linux:

```
system("clear");
```

Cleaning the terminal in Windows:

```
system("cls");
```